# Bootstraps' responsiveness relative to parent

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

When using the latest Bootstrap version, one can make use of the built-in responsiveness of Bootstrap.

One way to do this is by using the predefined grid layout. An example ([JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/n7zg5/)):

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3">col-xs-6 col-sm-3</div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3">col-xs-6 col-sm-3</div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3">col-xs-6 col-sm-3</div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3">col-xs-6 col-sm-3</div>
</div>
```

The `col-[screensize]-[colspan]` statement defines how much space each element should take.

Now I'm wondering: say you have a lay-out with 3 different columns. In one of these columns, there's a table.

When the column (**NOT** the window!) is bigger than `sm`, the table should have 4 columns, but if it's smaller, it should only have 2 columns.

Logically thinking, I would set up something like this ([JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3nXTL/1/)):

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4">col-sm-4</div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">col-sm-4
    <table class="table table-striped">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>TD 1</td>
                <td>TD 2</td>
                <td class="hidden-xs">TD 3 hidden-xs</td>
                <td class="hidden-xs">TD 4 hidden-xs</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="visible-xs">TD 3 visible-xs</td>
                <td class="visible-xs">TD 4 visible-xs</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">col-sm-4</div>
</div>
```

The problem here is that the table columns get showed based on the **window** width, ***NOT*** the **column** width, which is the desired behaviour.

Does anyone know how this can be achieved, e.g. responsiveness regarding the parent, not the window?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You can't achieve your goal with only css solution**.

This is justified by fact that table columns width depends by their content, or indirectly, by window width (if columns width is expressed in %).

*So you should use jQuery in order to "detect" actual column width, and then take a specific actions.*

In my opinion you could use jQuery to toggle "`display:none;`" / "`display:table-cell`" for last two columns depending by width detected on other ones.